# Django / Twisted (or hendrix) help to start

Tags: django, twisted, hendrix

I'm involve in a new proyect, let explain it briefly.
We have an application server, this server can be interfaces with other systems using udp (this is a design policy, I can change it).
Now we need a web app to collect the information sended by the application servers to show some reports and send back some configuration when we need.
We are very interested in Django with Twisted (or Hendrix), we are very new in python world, I surf in Internet for days and so far I undersand some concepts but I mess about how to start with a proof of concept, so I'm here.

I need an example or guide about how to start, our idea is simple for this proof of concept.
An Application server send some data over udp.
A twisted/django app receive that info and save it in a database table.
A django web page read the database table and show a report. I don't know if the web page need to run on twisted or not.

Please, I read a lot of post for days and I'm lost about how to start.

Thank you a lot in advance.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn each part of your stack one-by-one.  Start by following a [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/), then once you're comfortable with Django run the app using [Hendrix](https://hendrix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead of Django's `manage.py`, finally add your UDP tasks via [Twisted](http://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core/howto/udp.html) from Hendrix.  Lucky for you all the projects you've mentioned have good communities and documentation.  You don't have to get everything working perfectly, just get some working pieces.

Write some code, then when you have some running code and you get stuck somewhere, hop back onto Stackoverflow and ask your specific questions.

#### Update

As it so happens, there's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92VeMkjM1TQ) which shows how to integrate Django + Hendrix.  Give it a shot and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Hi notorious, thanks for answer and your link, the video was very useful, in facts, rigth now I'm writing my first test app and I have another issue, probably I miss something, I'll put another post. Thank you again