# Hendrix missing admin django template

Tags: python, django, hendrix

I'm starting my first demo app with Hendrix, my firsts steps come from here ([Django / Twisted (or hendrix) help to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38915054/django-twisted-or-hendrix-help-to-start)).

Right now I create the project and only do this
1- Add sitetree extension
2- run migrate to create database
3- create super user

When I run "hx start" and enter to admin app, every thing works perfect, but when start the project using this script

```
from hendrix.deploy.base import HendrixDeploy
deploy = HendrixDeploy (options={'wsgi':'portal.wsgi.application'})

deploy.run()
```

The project start without error but the template for Admin app is missing, probably I forgot something, but I don't know what.

Thank you in advance for any help.
Best Regards

Comment: Hey there.  How are you?  Can you provide more details about the error you're encountering?